# What was Ted referring to when he said: "You were lying about that?"

Tags: movie, bill-and-ted

In [Bill & Ted Face the Music](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1086064/), Bill and Ted travel to 2025, where they have seemingly become successful. However, they are tricked by their future counterparts, who try to pass off a song by Dave Grohl as their own:

> Old Bill: You have to! It's your only chance to get our wives back.
>
> Young Ted: You were lying about **that**?
>
> Older Ted: Of course we were lying.

What does "that" refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's a reference to the fact that the older Bill & Ted previously told them that the princesses had come back to them, when in reality they had not.

[Bill & Ted: Face the Music script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/bill-and-ted-face-the-music-2020.pdf)

> **TED:** *So, then.. I guess you have the song?*
>
> **55 YR OLD TED:** *Why would we be living like this if we
> didn’t?*
>
> **TED:** *And the princesses..?*
>
> **55 YR OLD BILL:** *Brace yourselves.. Are you ready?*
>
> **55 YR OLD TED:** *They’re back.*
>
> Bill and Ted audibly exhale.
>
> **55 YR OLD TED:** *They’ve been back for a while. And things
> are better than ever.*
>
> Huge loads are lifted from Bill and Ted’s shoulders.
>
> **TED:** *Oh, that’s such a relief.*